# Google's V8 Javascript Engine in .Net?

Tags: .net, javascript, v8

Has anyone been able to do this?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356948

Answer (score 4):

Check these questions:

- [Embedding JavaScript engine into .NET (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172753)
- [Referencing Google’s V8 engine from a .NET app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356948)