# Any Javascript Engine for .NET/C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, javascript-engine

I'm looking for an open source javascript engine for .NET. Thanks.

Comment: For those who are just finding this page, there is now V8.NET at http://v8dotnet.codeplex.com/ as well.

Comment: As of 2013 there is a new project maintained by microsoft called [ClearScript](http://clearscript.codeplex.com/). It works very well and supports multiple javascript engines including googles V8 engine.

Comment: Multithreaded Javascript Engine for .NET
https://github.com/koculu/topaz

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check [Jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) which is a Javascript interpreter for .NET.

Answer (score 10):

Try Javascript .NET:

http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/

It implements Google V8. You can compile and run Javascript directly from .NET code with it, and supply CLI objects to be used by the Javascript code as well. And V8 is probably the best engine ever created in terms of performance, it generates native code from Javascript.

Answer (score 6):

There was, at one time, a clone of JavaScript [that ran on the DLR](http://blogs.msdn.com/deepak/archive/2007/05/02/managed-jscript-is-availaible.aspx). [**But now it's dead**](http://dlr.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=58121).

A quick search turns up [RemObjects Script](http://code.remobjects.com/p/roscript/) and [ECMAScript.NET](http://code.google.com/p/ecmascript-net/). Might as well start there...

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [Managed JScript](http://blogs.msdn.com/jscript/archive/2007/05/07/introducing-managed-jscript.aspx).  It sounds like something you are looking for, but I don't really know much about it.

**Edit:** Sounds like Managed JScript is dead according to another post, so I would look into Google's V8.

You can also use Google's V8 Engine from .NET.  Check out this other question, and the provided solution: [Referencing Google's V8 engine from a .NET app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356948).  This example uses Managed C++.

Answer (score 2):

If your point 'engine' is Javascript Parser,I think MS JScript.NET has the ability to do this,Take a look this article:http://www.odetocode.com/code/80.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at this project http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/ which look like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean 'engine for .net'?

Regardless, there is Microsofts AJAX Framework, or jQuery. Microsofts is integrated via controls and so on, but I prefer jQuery.

Comment: He means a JavaScript interpreter that runs on .NET. Like IronPython or IronRuby.

Comment: Probably because the implementations I mentioned are written in C#, AFAIK anyway.

Comment: Well, I don't really buy it, but anyway, I think we can agree the question isn't worded well :) Hopefully he clarifies.

Comment: i think Alon might mean a .Net-based Javascript language interpreter and renderer. An engine that reads Javascript and executes the commands. 

Nothing about .Net with a quick Google search but you might consider porting from Java to .Net: http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/

Answer (score -4):

Here's a recent project I came across: script_sharp, to write JavaScript using the C# language. You write it in C# and it gets turned into JavaScript.

http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2009/08/11/script-script-sharp-solving-the-javascript-overload-problem.aspx

Comment: Never thought I'd downvote a post about script#... It's an excellent tool (possibly the best thing that has happened to MS web development since ASP.NET, but it does not target the problem the question is about.