# Can you call COM components from server side javascript?

Tags: windows, com, v8, serverside-javascript

Is it possible (using one of the server side implementations of javascript .. see http://www.nakedjavascript.com/getting-started-55) to instantiate a COM object and invoke methods on it?

Comment: I'm most interested in a v8 solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [node-win32ole](https://www.npmjs.com/package/win32ole) (`npm install win32ole`).

Answer (score 1):

That depends on which server-side implementation you’re using.
When using ASP/JS (or any other framework using Microsoft’s [Windows Scripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbxc2t98%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) engine), that’s not a problem using the [ActiveXObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) constructor.
When using [JSDB](http://www.jsdb.org/), you can use the [ActiveX](http://www.jsdb.org/activex.html) constructor.

[Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) doesn’t really work on Windows, only thru Cygwin, so ActiveX probably won’t be supported.

I have no idea how easy or difficult it would be to access COM objects from SpiderMonkey, V8 or SquirrelFish directly.  They have C/C++ interfaces — and are open source, so if you know your way in the language, you could probably add it.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I guess I could wrap COM using something like https://github.com/tsa/vu8 . I have no idea how much work that would be. What interfaces would you need as a minimum? I guess ruby's win32ole.c could be a good place to starthttp://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/

Comment: Also, I don’t know if .Net is an option, but in that case you should check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356948/referencing-googles-v8-engine-from-a-net-app).