# how to create a ActiveXObject with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a totally newbie in `node.js`. I'm trying to implement a browser performance tool using node.js, so I have the following piece of code:

```
 for(var j=0; j < 14; j++) {
        // Create a new instance of HttpWatch in Firefox
        var control = new ActiveXObject('HttpWatch.Controller');
        var plugin = control.Firefox.New();
        // Start Recording HTTP traffic
        plugin.Log.EnableFilter(false);
        // Clear Cache and cookier before each test
        plugin.ClearCache();
        plugin.ClearAllCookies();   
        plugin.ClearSessionCookies();
        plugin.Record();
        // Goto to the URL and wait for the page to be loaded
        plugin.GotoURL(url);
        control.Wait(plugin, -1);
        // Stop recording HTTP
        plugin.Stop();
        if ( plugin.Log.Pages.Count != 0 )
        {           
           // Display summary statistics for page
           var summary = plugin.Log.Pages(0).Entries.Summary;
           //WScript.Echo( "Iteration number " + j + "for" + url + "   Total time to load page in (secs): " + summary.Time);
           cache[i].value.push(summary.Time);
        }
        // Close down Firefox
        plugin.CloseBrowser();
      }
```

I'm using [httpwatch](http://www.httpwatch.com/) to measure the performance values, which are going to be stored in a `MySQL` database.
However, when I run:

```
node test.js
```

I get:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\test\browser-perf>node test.js

C:\xampp\htdocs\test\browser-perf\test.js:37
                var control = new ActiveXObject('HttpWatch.Controller');
                                  ^
ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\browser-perf\test.
js:37:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

How can I create a similar object as `ActiveXObject` in `node.js` and obtain the same desired results?

Comment: From what I'm reading I am not sure if you really understood what node.js and who it works. Have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1884724/45786

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14356064/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

https://npmjs.org/package/win32ole

try the win32ole package, to install, open the node.js cmd, and type the following to install the package.

```
npm install win32ole
```

Example usage:

```
var win32ole = require('win32ole');
var xl = win32ole.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application');
xl.Visible = true;
```

Please also see this post: [Using COM object in NodeJS](https://helloacm.com/using-com-object-in-nodejs/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a node.js user, so I can't comment on node.js specifically, but `ActiveXObject` is a feature of the Microsoft Active Scripting JScript engine, as well as the new Chakra engine in IE9, so it is not available in other platforms because it's very Windows-specific.

Comment: true, but I'm trying to run it from a windows terminal

Comment: Node.js runs in V8; It doesn't matter what OS you're running it in, you're still not going to have access to another engine's features.

Answer (score 1):

As in https://github.com/mynetx/codebird-js/issues/13, you can emulate it using `xhr2`: https://npmjs.org/package/xhr2.

```
npm install xhr2
```

I'm not sure if that will work for your browser performance tool but at least for someone else googling on the `ActiveXObject` error it should work.

Comment: That would only work with certain progids, such as the one for XHR.