# JavaScript Parser and Analyzer in C# .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, .net-4.5

Not sure if the title explains it correctly.

Anyways, I'm building a .NET WPF application which should go through the JavaScript and identify issues such as

1. If the variables defined are being nullified at the end
2. If try/catch/finally blocks are being used.
3. Function calls

I went through the questions over here which were all revolving around c/c++. Now I regret bunking my compilers classes.

I wanted to know how to verify points 1-3 in C#. Any library out there which does this?

Comment: Is there a question inside your posting?

Comment: Edited the question. Eg. I want to check in C#, if a variable defined in a JS function is being nullified or not.

Comment: I would suggest that you take a look at [V8](https://code.google.com/p/v8/), the JavaScript engine of Google. [There is a similar SO question (and answer) on how to use V8 from within C#/.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356948/referencing-googles-v8-engine-from-a-net-app). With this engine, you could compile your script and let it run, possibly seeing compiler warnings/errors.

Comment: BTW: Why do you consider "function calls" as being issues? I think function calls are a pretty good thing, actually!

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't think it'll throw any warnings for the issues 1 and 2. And, by 3 I meant to write External Library Function calls.

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is an [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) parser for Javascript written in C#.

There are a few choices I know of:

Microsoft's Ajax Minifier library comes with its own AST parser (used to minify / optimize Javascript files). You can find the source code for that on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/ajaxmin/blob/master/AjaxMinDll/JavaScript/jsparser.cs).

[Esprima.net](https://github.com/Diullei/Esprima.NET) is another option. It's a port of the popular Javascript library [Esprima](http://www.esprima.org).

The good thing about Esprima is it outputs the AST in a common format (defined by Mozilla [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API)) that's used across a few parsers, making it really easy to port utilities for walking the tree, etc. since they all use the same underlying data structure.

Answer (score 3):

Check out IronJS I know they have a pretty good JavaScript library for .Net

[IronJS](https://github.com/fholm/IronJS)